# Active directory authentication with user credentials and roles

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Am new to Active Directory authentication and asp.net. I want to implement active directory authentication with following filters:
a. User will login with his system credentials.
b. Need to validate user name and password using AD, if password/name not matching should be reported.
c. Need to get User Role from server so that i can implement page access rights in my application.
d. I want to verify 3 types of users 1. Admin, 2. non-admin and 3. Not registered user. So that based on roles i can configure page access rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found simple solution which can be used for AD authentication with user role easily. For this we need basically following inputs:
1. LDAPServerAddress
2. Group name: admin, users or others group.
After getting above information created a common library project with following code and import into your project.
Step1: Create library project in VS.
step2: Create AD object class as below:

```
public class ActiveDirectoryInfo
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public bool IsAuthentic { get; set; }
        public string UserDisplayName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string LdapServerName { get; set; }
        public string AdminGroupName { get; set; }
        public string UserGroupName { get; set; }
        public enum Role { Administrator, User, ReadOnly };
        public Role Authorization { get; set; }
    }
```

Step 3: Using above object and values check AD using below code:

```
 public class ActiveDirectoryHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Private variable for Principal Context
    /// </summary>
    private PrincipalContext context = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Public property for Principal Context
    /// </summary>
    public PrincipalContext Context
    {
        get { return context; }
        set { context = value; }
    }

    public ActiveDirectoryInfo adInfo = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor 
    /// </summary>
    public ActiveDirectoryHelper(ActiveDirectoryInfo adInfo)
    {
        context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adInfo.LdapServerName + ":636", null, ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate); //'636 is the port used Secure connection'
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Check if the user is Authentic in Active Directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">UserName</param>
    /// <param name="password">Password</param>
    /// <returns>IsAuthentic</returns>
    public bool IsAuthenticUser(ActiveDirectoryInfo adInfo)
    {

        try
        {
            adInfo.IsAuthentic = context.ValidateCredentials(adInfo.UserName, adInfo.Password, ContextOptions.ServerBind);
        }

        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Invalid User Name or Password", aex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Could not authenticate User", ex);
        }
        return adInfo.IsAuthentic;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To get the Display UserName from Active Directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">UserName</param>       
    /// <returns>UserDisplayName</returns>
    public string AuthenticUserName(ActiveDirectoryInfo adInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
            user.SamAccountName = adInfo.UserName;
            // perform the search 
            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
            user = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();
            search.Dispose();
            adInfo.UserDisplayName = user.DisplayName;
        }

        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Invalid User Name ", aex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Error in AuthenticateUserName ", ex.InnerException);
        }

        return adInfo.UserDisplayName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// To Check if the User belongs to a Authorized group in Active Directory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">UserName</param>
    /// <param name="password">Password</param>
    /// <returns>UserRole</returns>
    public ActiveDirectoryInfo.Role AuthorizedGroup(ActiveDirectoryInfo adInfo)
    {

        try
        {
            GroupPrincipal adminGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, adInfo.AdminGroupName);
            GroupPrincipal userGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Name, adInfo.UserGroupName);
            UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
            user.SamAccountName = adInfo.UserName;
            PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
            user = (UserPrincipal)search.FindOne();
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            // check if user is member of that group
            if (groups.Contains(adminGroup))
            {
                adInfo.Authorization = ActiveDirectoryInfo.Role.Administrator;
            }
            else if (groups.Contains(userGroup))
            {
                adInfo.Authorization = ActiveDirectoryInfo.Role.User;
            }
            else
            {
                adInfo.Authorization = ActiveDirectoryInfo.Role.ReadOnly;
            }
        }

        catch (System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException ienumarex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Invalid Group Name", ienumarex.InnerException);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException aex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("Invalid User Name or Password", aex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogInfo.LogNLogUnhandledError("User Cannot be Authorised", ex.InnerException);
        }

        return adInfo.Authorization;
    }
}
```